# AWS Amplify. Domain Status: Availible but: This site can’t be reached - DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I just recently setup an AWS Amplify App and pointed my Google Domain to Route 53 as a Hosted Zone.

I ran the Add domain setup in Domain management and it pulled the domain from Route 53 and I just did the default configuration.

The status now shows as Available:

[image]

and it looks like it added some extra records to the Route53 Records

[image]

When I try to access the domain I just get a generic.

This site can't be reached.

Check if there is a typo in www.*.family

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

I'm not sure what else to do, the status shows as available and there's no way to troubleshoot in the dashboard.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: mine was working until amplify broke. my cert renew.  so i removed it and added it again not i just get server can't be found.